# Where to Start with Declarative on Trailhead

Tags: trailhead

My development team is getting ready to transform our organization onto the Salesforce platform - No small task. I am hearing the best place to start is with declarative Salesforce so we know what can be done out of the box before we start coding the solution. This makes sense to me but when on Trailhead it's not apparent where this training is; I suspect it's all over the place.

Which Trailhead courses would you recommend?
Which [tags](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails) should I use for searching?

Trailhead really doesn't define [declarative](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/search?keywords=declarative) tracks, per se

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search with Admin or Administration related trailheads to start with. Declarative means click and not to code and doing with configurations.

Start with  Admin beginner and Admin Intermediate Trails which contains respective modules.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this trail but it looks like a good fit for you: [Admin Beginner](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_admin_beginner). Also possibly useful: [Learn CRM Essentials](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/getting_started_crm_basics).

As far as baseline skills, here are some of the biggest declarative building blocks:

- [Formulas & Validations](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/point_click_business_logic)
- [Customize the User Interface](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_migration_customization/units/lex_migration_customization_layouts_ui)
- Workflow & Process Builder

  - [Automate Your Business Processes](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/automate_business_processes)

Also, while it's not Trailhead, learn to know and love this tool: **[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)**